# How to allocate size of Netcdf fortran array at run time?

Tags: fortran, netcdf

I have a netCDF 4.4 file which has four dimensions- time, latitude,longitude, level. I want to be able to read the latitude and longitude values  from this file and store them in a single dimensional array. However I do not know the size of the latitude array or longitude array and I so cannot allocate the size at the time of the declaration of the two arrays lat and lon. Each netCDF file that will be processed will have it's own lat and lon size and so it is not possible to declare this at compile time. So I did declare this using Fortran's allocate but this does not do what I want it to do. It prints 0 as the values of lats and lons. 
Where am I going wrong ?

```
  Variables for input Z file : height level
  character*80 in_cfn,varname
  integer      reason,i,in_ndim,ierr
  integer ndims_in, nvars_in, ngatts_in, unlimdimid_in
  integer lat_varid,lon_varid
  character*(*) LAT_NAME, LON_NAME
  parameter (LAT_NAME='lat', LON_NAME='lon')
  real,allocatable, dimension(:) :: lats
  real,allocatable, dimension(:) :: lons

  call system('ls hgt_*.nc > hgtFiles.txt')

  open(10,file='hgtFiles.txt',action="read")
  varname = "hgt"
  do
     read(10,*,IOSTAT=reason) in_cfn
     if (reason/=0) EXIT
     print *,in_cfn
     retval = nf_open(in_cfn,NF_NOWRITE,ncid)
     if (retval .ne. nf_noerr) call handle_err(retval)
     retval = nf_inq(ncid,ndims_in,nvars_in,ngatts_in,unlimdimid_in)
     retval = nf_inq_varid(ncid,LAT_NAME,lat_varid)
     if (retval .ne. nf_noerr) call handle_err(retval)
     retval = nf_inq_varid(ncid, LON_NAME, lon_varid)
     if (retval .ne. nf_noerr) call handle_err(retval)
     retval = nf_get_var_real(ncid, lat_varid, lats)
    if (retval .ne. nf_noerr) call handle_err(retval)
     retval = nf_get_var_real(ncid, lon_varid, lons)
     print *,size(lons)

  end do
  close(10)

  stop

  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm usually using [Fortran 90 NetCDF Module](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/netcdf-4/newdocs/netcdf-f90/index.html#Top). But the [Fortran 77 interface](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/netcdf-4/newdocs/netcdf-f77/index.html#Top) works similar.

You can get the length of a dimension with a call to [NF_INQ_DIMLEN](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/netcdf-4/newdocs/netcdf-f77/NF_005fINQ_005fDIM-Family.html#NF_005fINQ_005fDIM-Family)

I've made a Fortran 77 compliant (hopefully) program to read in the latitude array and print it to the screen:

```
      PROGRAM READ_LAT
        IMPLICIT NONE
        INCLUDE 'netcdf.inc'
        INTEGER NCID, LATID, LATVARID, LATLEN
        REAL LATDATA[ALLOCATABLE](:)
        CHARACTER*(*) FILENAME
        CHARACTER*(*) LATNAME
        PARAMETER (FILENAME='data.nc', LATNAME='lat')

        CALL CHECK( NF_OPEN(FILENAME, NF_NOWRITE, NCID) )
        CALL CHECK( NF_INQ_DIMID(NCID, LATNAME, LATID) )
        CALL CHECK( NF_INQ_DIMLEN(NCID, LATID, LATLEN) )

        ALLOCATE(LATDATA(LATLEN))

        CALL CHECK( NF_INQ_VARID(NCID, LATNAME, LATVARID) )
        CALL CHECK( NF_GET_VAR_REAL(NCID, LATVARID, LATDATA) )

        WRITE(*, '(F10.4)') LATDATA

        CALL CHECK( NF_CLOSE(NCID) )

      CONTAINS

        SUBROUTINE CHECK( ERRORCODE )
            IMPLICIT NONE
            INTEGER ERRORCODE
            IF (ERRORCODE .ne. NF_NOERR) THEN
                PRINT *, "Encountered Error ", ERRORCODE
                STOP
            END IF
        END SUBROUTINE
      END PROGRAM
```

Same program as Fortran 90+:

```
program read_latitude
    use netcdf
    implicit none
    integer :: ncid, latid, latvarid, latlen
    real, allocatable :: latdata(:)
    character(len=*), parameter :: filename='data.nc'
    character(len=*), parameter :: latname = 'lat'

    call check( nf90_open(filename, NF90_NOWRITE, ncid) )
    call check( nf90_inq_dimid(ncid, latname, latid) )
    call check( nf90_inquire_dimension(ncid, latid, len=latlen) )

    allocate( latdata(latlen) )

    call check( nf90_inq_varid(ncid, latname, latvarid) )
    call check( nf90_get_var(ncid, latvarid, latdata) )

    write(*, '(F10.4)') latdata

    call check( nf90_close(ncid) )

    contains

        subroutine check(errorcode)
            implicit none
            integer, intent(in) :: errorcode
            if (errorcode /= NF90_NOERR) then
                write(*, '(A, I0)') "Encountered Error ", errorcode
                write(*, '(A)') nf90_strerror(errorcode)
                stop 1
            end if
        end subroutine check
end program read_latitude
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Assuming I do call that function do I still need to allocate arrays using allocate dimension(:) ?

Comment: Yes. That call gives you the length of the dimension. Then you know how large an array you need to allocate.

Comment: Just to let you know, I've added two examples, one for F77, and one for F90+

Comment: when I run this I get a run time error - allocatable array already allocated

Comment: Interesting, which one of the two are you executing? The F77 or the F90 one? I tested both with an Intel Compiler (and the F90 with gfortran. The F77 won't work with gfortran because it doesn't recognise this `[ALLOCATABLE]` declaration.)

Comment: Wait, are you doing that while looping over several netcdf files? In that case you have to `DEALLOCATE(latdata)` once you're finished with the file data.